Android Studio Extendded Controls Gps Simulator blank
the android studio controls doest show the map for gps simulation

it should be like this

Im trying to use the androi studio extended controls for gps simulation and it end up in a blank state , i want to simulate my cycling application through the gps simulator but i cannot access the extended control
